# Stop Mirth Connect keepalive messages from SFTP File Reader connector

Tags: sftp, jsch, mirth, mirth-connect

My Mirth Connect v3.4 channel's *File Reader* source connector is configured as the SFTP reader to poll files from a remote server every 20 minutes and it works as expected.

But when the channel goes idle it starts sending keepalive@jcraft.com messages to the remote server every 10 seconds regardless of the *Timeout* setting of that source connector.

Is there anything else to configure to stop these messages from being sent to keep connection alive or is there any workarounds other than restarting the channel after each poll by some other channel?

Answer (score 1):

From the JSch changelog:

> - change: at TCP socket reading timeout, keep-alive message will be sent
>           to the remote sshd.  To disable this functionality, invoke
>           explicitly Session.setServerAliveCountMax(0)

Unfortunately JSch does not provide any way to set this value from its own configuration file. So you'll have to use JavaScript and create a Session manually.

Comment: What's source connector's Timeout do in this case? If I'm correct it sets the JSch session.timeout. Mirth default is 10 sec, JSch default for this is "0" sec. If I set it to "0" presumably it should set timeout to infinite, is it not?  Also, is there any way to force closing JSch session and connection from Mirth without writing my own JSch script (certainly this is an option but if you've done this already with File Reader, why to re-write).